# Uploading Album to User's wall has stopped working

Tags: facebook

For quite some time we've been uploading albums to Facebook User's walls. It suddenly stopped working in the last several days with a slightly ambiguous message.

OAuthException :: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

I've checked permissions and have tried granting more and I get the same error. I can post albums to a Page's wall no problem. I can also post single pictures to a User's wall, along with text posts.

Here's the code that fails now. It fails on the `fb_user.album!(:name => caption)` call,

```
user = User.find(user_id)
folder = Folder.find(folder_id)

fb_user = FbGraph::User.me(user.facebook_access_token)
fb_album = fb_user.album!(:name => caption)

folder.user_files.each do |file|
  fb_album.photo!(
    :message => file.caption,
    :url => file.file.url,
    :no_story => post_to_feed
  )
end
```

Comment: How could we help you just like that, pls show some code!

Comment: @SahilMittal I've added the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question semmons99. The Facebook API docs* suggest that since you are working with a User object, the user_photos permission is required. I have tested this and it seems to be working. :)

*https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/